# React accessing a property of an object returns old data, when object has been updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in my component props which I'll call `data`.  This object is updated dynamically. However a problem arises when I try to get a property of the `data` object, it returns the old data from the object, even though the object is updated.

For example `console.log(data)` returns

```
{
    items: [{name: "NEW NAME"}]
}
```

But that's not  the case when I try to access the property directly, because `console.log(data.items[0].name)` returns `"OLD NAME"`.
I'm pretty sure the component updates since the object contains the new data. The problem is that it renders the older name.

Another details is that it returns what the previous name was, so for example if I pass new data `console.log(data)` returns

```
{
    items: [{name: "EVEN NEWER NAME"}]
}
```

while `console.log(data.items[0].name)` would return `"NEW NAME"`.

I'll gladly provide more info if needed.

Comment: Where do you update your data? Can you share your Component's code?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to modify the prop or a state object directly. They are read only and need to be reset using setState for example with new copies of the value

Answer (score 1):

Objects are evaluated each time it's value is changed in browser's dev tools. So even if the the object was {name: "OLD NAME"} when the console.log runs, it's value gets updated later and displays {name: "NEW NAME"}

But when you console data.items[0].name it's returning a string "OLD NAME" and it won't get evaluated automatically in Dev tools later. I would suggest rendering it on the page instead of using console to check if it's getting updated correctly

Comment: It still renders "OLD NAME", that's how I found out about the problem and decided to log everything